# d3.js combines two different types of json file with same properties

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am confused about combining two different types of json file.
Because I want to build a json file which uses same properties to connect each json file. All of this are based on d3.js structure.

The first json file is shown as following:

```
[{"status":"Active",
  "name":"public",
  "router:external":true,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"dfc69b95-915f-475c-8800-db6c4e15c290"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"UTAH",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"1b12abc7-6f69-493d-b95a-8fd9f8d15643"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"USCB",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"5280be34-8e77-457c-856d-cd9776841cda"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"UCLA",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"82d4cc54-471b-456e-8c28-da04226ee344"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"SRI",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"e802c8fe-b30e-40c8-8f1d-fb8631bb0601"}
]
```

The second json file is shown as following:

```
{
"SRI": [-122.18219, 37.45383],
"USCB": [-119.69819, 34.42083],
"UCLA": [-118.24368, 34.05223],
"UTAH": [-111.89105, 40.76078]
}
```

As you can see, the same property is the **name**, so I want to use the name to build a connection and combine a json file, which has a **coordinates properties**. Just like this:

```
[{"status":"Active",
  "name":"public",

  "lot": null,
  "lat": null,

  "router:external":true,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"dfc69b95-915f-475c-8800-db6c4e15c290"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"UTAH",

  "lot":"-111",
  "lat":"40",

  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"1b12abc7-6f69-493d-b95a-8fd9f8d15643"},
....
```

Could you please tell me how to achieve this? Thanks for all of your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question has nothing to do with D3, you can do that with plain JavaScript.

Supposing the first JSON is named `json1` and the second one is named `json2`, you can do:

```
json1.forEach(function(d){
    d.lat = json2[d.name] ? json2[d.name][1] : null;
    d.lon = json2[d.name] ? json2[d.name][0] : null
});
```

That will create new properties in `json1` objects, based on `json2`.

Here is the demo:

```js
var json1 = [{
  "status": "Active",
  "name": "public",
  "router:external": true,
  "original_status": "ACTIVE",
  "id": "dfc69b95-915f-475c-8800-db6c4e15c290"
}, {
  "status": "Active",
  "name": "UTAH",
  "router:external": false,
  "original_status": "ACTIVE",
  "id": "1b12abc7-6f69-493d-b95a-8fd9f8d15643"
}, {
  "status": "Active",
  "name": "USCB",
  "router:external": false,
  "original_status": "ACTIVE",
  "id": "5280be34-8e77-457c-856d-cd9776841cda"
}, {
  "status": "Active",
  "name": "UCLA",
  "router:external": false,
  "original_status": "ACTIVE",
  "id": "82d4cc54-471b-456e-8c28-da04226ee344"
}, {
  "status": "Active",
  "name": "SRI",
  "router:external": false,
  "original_status": "ACTIVE",
  "id": "e802c8fe-b30e-40c8-8f1d-fb8631bb0601"
}];

var json2 = {
  "SRI": [-122.18219, 37.45383],
  "USCB": [-119.69819, 34.42083],
  "UCLA": [-118.24368, 34.05223],
  "UTAH": [-111.89105, 40.76078]
};

json1.forEach(function(d) {
  d.lat = json2[d.name] ? json2[d.name][1] : null;
  d.lon = json2[d.name] ? json2[d.name][0] : null
});

console.log(json1);
```

Comment: I thought about the forEach method, but I am confused about the second json file with the format. Now, I totally understood. Thanks in heart, saved me again:>)

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = [{"status":"Active",
  "name":"public",
  "router:external":true,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"dfc69b95-915f-475c-8800-db6c4e15c290"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"UTAH",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"1b12abc7-6f69-493d-b95a-8fd9f8d15643"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"USCB",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"5280be34-8e77-457c-856d-cd9776841cda"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"UCLA",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"82d4cc54-471b-456e-8c28-da04226ee344"},
 {"status":"Active",
  "name":"SRI",
  "router:external":false,
  "original_status":"ACTIVE",
  "id":"e802c8fe-b30e-40c8-8f1d-fb8631bb0601"}
]

var second = {
"SRI": [-122.18219, 37.45383],
"USCB": [-119.69819, 34.42083],
"UCLA": [-118.24368, 34.05223],
"UTAH": [-111.89105, 40.76078]
}

var res = first.map(d => {
    if(second[d.name]) {
    let arr = second[d.name];
    d.lat = arr[0];
    d.lom = arr[1];
  }
  else {
    d.lat = null;
    d.lon = null;
  }
  return d; 
});

console.log(res);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GunnerSS/dvu0L463/